# How to disable popup “disable popup?” when press Ctrl+C

Tags: kubuntu, kde

This popup comes up in many situations when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and is very, very hindering:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-53-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed a hotkey at in [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper/en):

1. Open [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper/en) at Mouse Position > Config Plasma > Open Clipper at Mouse Position = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>
2. delete the HotKey

the annoying the effect is gone. funny. I just have to remove my [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper/en) hotkey.

3. I then do the same hotkey there again.

But the disturbing effect did not return. so repaired. I can't explain it, but that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable it from the clipboard manager. It's the immediately on selection.

[image: Immediately on selection]